# iOS UIDatePicker always returns today's date

Tags: ios, swift, date, uidatepicker

There is similar question on Stack Overflow, but the problem there was different then mine, so I feel free to open this one.

I have iOS view controller with a UIDatePicker defined in storyboard. 
I have defined(connected) IBOutlet in view controller code like this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var endTimeDatePicker: UIDatePicker!
```

At one point I set initial date like this:

```
endTimeDatePicker.date = state!.endTime;
```

or like this:

```
endTimeDatePicker.setDate(state!.endTime, animated: true);
```

and it shows correct date indicating that date picker is connected correctly.

But then, if I pick another date and try to get selected date with endTimeDatePicker.date  it always returns the same - today's date, no matter what I pick.

Storyboard properties for date picker are:
Mode - Date and Time
Interval - 1 minute
Date - Current Date (but it's the same with custom, only returning defined custom date every time)

Is there something that I've missed to do?

I don't have for sure two different datePickers (like in potential duplicate Stack Overflow questions)

EDIT: looks like it only happens when Date Picker has set initial value from code.

EDIT: code that sets Date Picker:

```
 private func reloadData (state : State?)
    {
        if (state != nil)
        {
            endTimeDatePicker.setDate(state!.endTime, animated: true);

            backgroundImage.image = UIImage(named: state!.type.imageName)!;
        }
        else
        {
            let endDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 1800);
            endTimeDatePicker.setDate(endDate, animated: true);
            backgroundImage.image = UIImage(named: StateType.Active.imageName);
        }
    }
```

Code that tries to read selected date:

```
 @IBAction func doneTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

        let row: Int = self.stateTypePicker.selectedRowInComponent(0);


        state = State (id: -1, type: stateTypes[row], startTime: NSDate(), endTime: self.endTimeDatePicker.date);

        service.addState(state!) {
            (responseDict) in
        }
    }
```

func reloadData is called in callback for http request. Could be thread lock problem maybe?

Comment: Could you provide the code where you try to access `endTimeDatePicker.date`?

Comment: How are you setting the initial value? Are you sure it doesn't get called/initialised several times?

Comment: I provided code above in the second EDIT. 
I use  endTimeDatePicker.setDate(endDate, animated: true);
to set initial date value.

Comment: And when do you call reloadData? Plus, when do you access `endTimeDatePicker.date`?

Comment: Scenario is: 
1.) I make request to server (using NSURLSession) on viewDidLoad  
2.) In response callback I call reloadData
3.) I access  endTimeDatePicker.date latter when clicking on Done button trying to get picked date value

Comment: Could you provide the code for the `Done` button to confirm that the bug doesn't lie there?

Comment: Sure: 
 @IBAction func doneTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
        
        let row: Int = self.stateTypePicker.selectedRowInComponent(0);
    
        
        state = State (id: -1, type: stateTypes[row], startTime: NSDate(), endTime: self.endTimeDatePicker.date);
        
        service.addState(state!) {
            (responseDict) in
        }
    }

Comment: And if you put a print statement (like this one: `print("Date is: \(endTimeDatePicker.date)")`) in the first line of that action method, then it confirms that the date picker always returns today's date? If so, then your bug must lie somewhere else in your code/storyboard.

Comment: Yes, I just tried it, it returns today's date

Comment: But if I remove call to reload data then it works fine...that makes me think if there could happen some thread lock or something...

Comment: The problem is probably that you are updating the `UIDatePicker` in a background thread, but all UI updates have to be done on the main thread. That is most likely why you are seeing todays date. So try to run `reloadData` on the main thread and see if that solves your issue

Comment: Yes, looks like that was the case.

Comment: If you post that as an answer I can accept it, or how that usually works? :)

Comment: I will make an official answer then ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is related to the callback method `reloadData` from the `NSURLSession`. In here, you are updating the `UIDatePicker` in a background thread, but all UI updates have to be done on the main thread.

This is the reason why you are seeing todays date, when you are reading the `date` property of the `UIDatePicker`.